# Definition of limits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, definition

I have this following equation that I and my classmates have different opinions on. We're supposed to prove the limits using the formal definition.

Here is the question, and my method of approaching it. Please tell me if I am doing it wrong or not approaching it the right way.
[image]
P.S: If you are about to tell me to ask my professor, well... He doesn't like to help that much.

Comment: $\left | {1 \over x} -{1 \over 2} \right | = \left | {1 \over 2x} (2-x) \right | $

Comment: Note: $\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2} \ne 1/2 (2x-4)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may suppose $x>0$. Then the condition to be satisfied is
$$\biggl|\frac 1x-\frac12\biggr|=\biggl|\frac{x-2}{2x}\biggr|<\varepsilon\iff|x-2|<2\,\varepsilon |x|<2\,\varepsilon(|x-2|+2)=2\,\varepsilon|x-2|+4\varepsilon, $$
so , if $\;\varepsilon<\frac12 $, we obtain
$$|x-2|<\frac{4\varepsilon}{1-2\varepsilon}.$$

Comment: Hey, @Bernard I know this sounds ridiculous, but our professor told us to do it only the way I've done it at the top. The reason being is he wants to explore different methods later, but right now I have to do it using the method supplied above. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you factor a $1/2$ out of a $-\frac{1}{2}$, you are left with $-1$, not $4$.

If you factor a $1/2$ out of a term $\frac{1}{x}$, you are left with $\frac{1}{2x}$, not $2x$.